# Azurite only with http?

Tags: spring, azureservicebus, azurite

I have to use azurite as broker, unfortunately I can't use azure service bus yet. So I was forced to use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-servicebus-jms-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

But with azurite container for JmsListener.

```
  @JmsListener(destination = QUEUE_NAME, containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactory")
    public void receiveMessage(String message) {
        logger.info("Received message: {}", message);
    }
```

Inside factory, deeply nested in stackTrace is ConnectionStringBuilder which appends "amqps://";
and removes port number. The problem is that I don't know how to change messaging protocol in azurite for amqps from http and If it is not possible. How to overrite classes to use http not not amqps?

Comment: I'm somewhat confused. Are you referring to [Azurite](https://github.com/Azure/Azurite/), a storage service emulator?

Comment: Azurite is queue and blob. But I refere to queue. I want to implement listening mechanism for messages from queueus

Comment: azure-servicebus-jms-spring-boot-starter is using AMQPS not HTTP but Azurite is using HTTP. Is it even possible to uses AMQPS on azurite? If not how to listen via Spring for http messages from azurite

Comment: Azurite is intended for Azure Queue Storage, not Azure Service Bus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azurite is intended for Azure Queue Storage, not Azure Service Bus. Azure Queue Storage is HTTP/S only and the tool was never designed to work with AMQP/S based services.

Comment: 1. Can I simulate  Azure Service Bus like Azurite for Azure Queue Storage ?
2. If not can I use some kind of listener for Azure Queue Storage?
3. What is a difference between  Azure Queue Storage, not Azure Service Bus ( but only queue part)

Comment: 1. You cannot at this point. 2. What does that even mean? Listener is a consumer. You consume the messages. 3. Service Bus is an advanced messaging service, Queue Storage is a simple queuing service.